# What do these HPROF errors mean?

Tags: java, debugging, weblogic, hprof

I'm seeing the following errors in my console logs:

```
HPROF ERROR: unable to resolve a method id
HPROF ERROR: got NULL trace in obj_alloc
HPROF ERROR: duplicate obj_id in object_alloc
HPROF ERROR: unable to resolve a method id
HPROF ERROR: got NULL trace in obj_alloc
HPROF ERROR: unable to resolve a method id
HPROF ERROR: got NULL trace in obj_alloc
HPROF ERROR: unable to resolve a method id
HPROF ERROR: got NULL trace in obj_alloc
HPROF ERROR: unable to resolve a method id
HPROF ERROR: got NULL trace in obj_alloc
HPROF ERROR: class ID already in use
```

I'm running on the BEA Weblogic App Server 8.1 with the SUN 1.4.2-12 JDK.

I'm passing these debugging flags to the JVM at startup:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xrunhprof:heap=sites,format=a,file=server1.endurance.txt
```

The error is output almost immediately after starting the server.

Any ideas what the errors mean?

Answer (score 1):

It could be either

- a bug in the JVM, try using a more up to date JVM and see if you get the same problem.
- you have a JNI library which is creating objects incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [reported bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5053405) may help you tracing you problem.

> **Synopsis:** GetThreadGroupInfo crashes if Thread Group name is null (jvmpi too)
>
> **Reported Against**: 1.4.2_03 , tiger-beta2
>
> **Release Fixed**     1.5(tiger-b56)
>
> **Evaluation:** Legacy java.lang.ThreadGroup allows the name to be null so the vm needs to
> allow for this.

As you are using a similar jvm I suggest to check the test code provided in the bug report to determine whether you have found the same bug.